# Why are the Kings of Narnia always "Emperor" of the Lone Islands?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis, prince-caspian

Whenever a King of Narnia's full title is mentioned in the Chronicles of Narnia, it is mentioned that he is "Emperor of the Lone Islands". Why are the Lone Islands always governed by an "Emperor"? Shouldn't the King of Narnia be a "King" over everything and not an "Emperor" over a select few islands?

Comment: Well, British Kings/Queens were for almost a century [Emperors of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_of_India).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per a reference in chapter 8 of The Last Battle, the Lone Islands made Gale the King of Narnia (and all his descendants) Emperor of the Lone Islands. Although sovereign of the lone islands, the islands were in fact governed by a governor, up until the point Caspian did away the post (since the recently deposed governor had been a thoroughly despicable man) and replaced it with a hereditary lord.

That king (or queen) could also be an emperor was rooted in historical fact, Queen Victoria was Empress of India but was Queen of the United Kingdom.

> "Victoria, in full Alexandrina Victoria, ... queen of the United
> Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland (1837–1901) and empress of India
> (1876–1901)."

https://www.britannica.com/biography/Victoria-queen-of-United-Kingdom

The specific title a monarch takes for each of their dominions often stems from how it was acquired. In this case, I think it is Lewis being dramatic, since Gale was granted the title for slaying a dragon, rather than through military conquest.

Comment: Could you add a reference?

Comment: The Last Battle quote is:  

He told how King Gale, who was ninth in descent from Frank the first of all Kings, had sailed far away into the Eastern seas and delivered the Lone Islanders from a dragon and how, in return, they had given him the Lone Islands to be part of the royal 
lands  of  Narnia  for  ever.

So, it does not explicitly state that the Lone Islanders named Gale emperor.

Comment: I suppose this makes sense. Thanks for the historical and book references. +1 and confirmed

Comment: That historical example (very recent at the time, as King George VI had only been forced to abandon the title “Emperor of India” three years before Lewis published *The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe*) might have come about because Queen Victoria’s daughter had married the oldest son of the King of Prussia, who then declared himself to be the Emperor of Germany. Suddenly, the younger Victoria was next in line to be Empress of Germany. Some suspect that Queen Victoria wanted to be an empress too because she would not let her daughter outrank her.

Comment: There's a few other examples historically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King-Emperor . Amusingly I was thinking of the king of prussia/Emperor of Germany but... there's more

Comment: @JourneymanGeek One of those examples is the King of Italy briefly declaring himself Emperor of Ethiopia after conquering it, back when Mussolini was the real ruler. This is another case of a King-Emperor using “Emperor” of a colony as a lesser title, but that would not have been a heroic or positive example for C.S. Lewis in the early postwar years.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The others listed there were of Emperors who were also the King of one or more parts of their empire. This example is perhaps more like the dual monarchy of Austria-Hungary, in that it is more of a personal union of a kingdom and an empire that are both autonomous, but have the same monarch. But the Habsburgs considered Emperor their highest title.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It’s more likely, given his background and audience, that Lewis meant to call back to the glory days of the British Empire than to its defeated, reviled enemies.

Comment: There are also several kings who were also Holy Roman Emperors.

Comment: I believe Victoria was Empress of India because India already had kings (Maharajahs). Being Queen of India would conflict with the Kings, but Kings are OK with having an Empress over them as long as they continue to be King. Maybe something similar applied to the Lone Islands.

Comment: A historian or political scholar may correct me, but often the distinction between King and Emperor is that your Kingdom typically incorporates just your homeland and possibly the surrounding area whereas your Empire includes all of the lands over which you are sovereign. So for a historical example a King of England was the King of the United Kingdom (i.e. England, Scotland, Wales, and Ireland) and Emperor of the British Empire (e.g. India, Australia, and other British colonies and territories)

Comment: @Kevin - As the old joke goes; We used to have kingdoms ruled by kings and empires ruled by emperors, now we have countries.

An empire would typically be extra-territorial land taken under direct control of the crown through military conquest. But if we look at how England came to be a unified country, we see that the difference is down to how the ruler themself chooses to describe their dominion.

Comment: In my opinion, only an avatar or incarnation of the Roman Empire can be an empire in European ciivlization.  All other alleged empires in European culture are more like inferiums than imperiums, and their rulers more like inferators than imperators.  And some some - but not all  - non European states which have been called empires may be considered to be  empire equivalents ruled by emperor equivalents.   As for the German  Empire, the King of Prussia and President of the North German Confederation was proclaimed  German Emperor in 1871, not Emperor of Germany,  Continued.

Comment: Continued.  The title was chosen carefully by Bismark for politcal reasons and displeased the new kaiser.  In India, the title of Maharaja is "great king" not "king", and both the Mughal Empire and the British Raj had rulers with much higher titles than that.  I believe that the highest Hindu title used during the Raj was Maharajadhiraja, "Great King of Kings".  When the British took over India they treated the Mughal Padishah with less and less respect.  They tried to get the various rulers to renounche loyalty to the Padishah and declare independence from him.  Continued.

Comment: Continued.  But only the monarch of Oudh did so.  The Briitsh deposed the last Padishah after the Mutiny in 1857-58.  Giving Victoria the title of Emperess of india had already been suggested as early as 1843, so there is no need to suppose that jealousy of Victoria's daughter's future title was the main reason for taking the title of Empress of India.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - None of those comments added anything to this answer. It's your opinion, which is evidently very different to C.S. Lewis' opinion and doesn't affect the official titles of real world historical figures.